# Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it

Tags: java, hadoop, jersey

When I deploy the war file in Weblogic server I am facing jars error
How to solve 'Jersey' and 'Hadoop' jar file errors in Web logic server for gateway connection?
I have attached the logs screenshot

[image: Link to the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore jersey warning if you can access your endpoint. 
For the class not found exception , please check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

add `hadoop-commons-xx.jar` in the classpath. that should solve the issue of CNF.